# BULK INSERT into specific columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, bulkinsert

I want to bulk insert columns of a csv file to specific columns of a destination table. 
Description - destination table has more columns than my csv file. So, I want the csv file columns to go to the right target columns using BULK INSERT.

Is this possible ? If yes, then how do I do it ?

I saw the tutorial and code at - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439843/Handling-BULK-Data-insert-from-CSV-to-SQL-Server

```
BULK INSERT dbo.TableForBulkData
FROM 'C:\BulkDataFile.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

They don't show you how you can control where data is inserted.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results.

Comment: What do you mean by inserting columns? don't you want all the data? You should show what you have and what exactly you want to do with it.

Comment: You will need to make use of Format File.

Comment: @MuhammedAli - can you please tell me more about how to to it ?

Comment: @Yosi - okay, I fixed it. Can I get 1 back now ?

Comment: Have a look here pal http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx once you have created a format file in bulk insert in with clause you pass the path for you format file sql server inserts the data into their respective column as defined in format file.

Comment: @blasto dont worry pal its a fashion here for some irresponsible people down voting :) I have upvoted you :) pal take it easy

Comment: @MuhammedAli - Thanks. I am looking for a short example on that now. The MS tutorial is too long. and thanks for the upvote. :)

Comment: Your looking for a silver bullet pal which does not exist :) spend some time understanding how to create a format file one you get your head around that it is piss easy to do it. Secondly you can arrange your data in the flat file in a way that it suits your table structure

Comment: @MuhammedAli Two points, 1) Format files are clumsy and rarely needed if you know what the other options are, and 2) There is indeed a silver bullet, it's called a View. (see my answer below)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  The easiest way is to just create a View that `Select`s from the target table, listing the columns that you want the data to go to, in the order that they appear in the source file.  Then `BULK INSERT` to your View instead of directly to the Table.

Comment: Wow ! How does this work ? Will it actually move data from my csv file to real table if i replace mytable with myview in the above code ?

Comment: Yup.  It will indeed.

Comment: Thanks. After exploring all the options, I am frustrated. I am going with C# and a bit of ssis. I am switching over to SQL statements instead of csv files. Thanks for showing me this alternate way. Its static, but good to know.

Comment: This is indeed amazing. I didn't know this.

Answer (score 0):

Really late to the party here, but I just had a situation that this was the right answer for and judging from the OP comments I thought the answer could use a little more clarification, so here goes.

The way this works is you have your permanent table you want the data from the `.csv` file to end up in. What you do is create a view of that table that only has the columns that match up with the columns in your `.csv` file. Then you upload the data from your `.csv` file to the view and behind the scenes Sql Server puts that data into your permanent table.

My situation is that I have a table where I have more columns than are in the source `.csv` file. Specifically, I had a GUID column I wanted to have the default value of `NEWSEQUENTIAL()` and also an INT column I wanted to have the default value of `IDENTITY(1,1)` for. This is a problem when trying to insert values from a `.csv` file because I couldn't find a way to insert the values from the `.csv` file while allowing the two columns in my permanent table (the GUID and the INT column) to be able to use the default values that would increment automatically.

Here's an example of the `CREATE TABLE` statement that will create my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyBaseTable](
    [MyBaseTableGUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
    [MyBaseTableRowID] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [SomeNumber] INT NOT NULL,
    [SomeText1] NVARCHAR(10) NULL,
    [SomeText2] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [SomeText3] NVARCHAR(50) NULL
GO
```

Here is an example of the data in my `.csv` file:

```
SomeNumber,SomeText1,SomeText2,SomeText3 
4,Hey,Hi,Hello 
2,Bye,Later,Good Bye
7,Yo,Sup,What's Up
```

To create the view of my table in Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS), I followed the instructions at [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-views?view=sql-server-2016) from Microsoft. On step 5 of these instructions, I selected all of the columns from my table except for the 2 columns that represented my GUID and my INT columns (so for my example when I created the view I selected the columns `SomeNumber`, `SomeText1`, `SomeText2` and `SomeText3` to be created in the view). For this example we'll say I named the view of `MyBaseTable` as `View_MyBaseTable`.

Then here is the `BULK INSERT` statement I used to insert the data from my `.csv` file into the view I just created:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[View_MyBaseTable]
FROM 'C:\\FullPathToMyCsvFile\MyCsvFile.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    FIRSTROW = 2
)
GO
```

Then when this completes, I can query `MyBaseTable` and all of the data from `MyCsvFile.csv` is in there and the GUID and INT columns are populated with the incrementing values like I wanted.

One thing to note: if you are doing a `BULK INSERT` like this, the `.csv` file needs to be in a location that the machine running the instance of Sql Server is on has access to. So, if your Sql Server database is on a network server, the `.csv` file needs to be either on a machine that has a network share that is visible to the Sql Server or else it needs to be directly on the server running the Sql Server instance.

I hope this clears up the solution and gives a more clear explanation of what is happening and how to do it.