# Error reading date variable from a textfile to sqlserver table

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

Am trying to CSV Data in notepad to my database,but am having conversion error.
I got similar error message but different problem after a lot of hours Researching on the issue. error message:

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified  codepage) for row 1, column 4 (HireDate).
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did  not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

File path:'c:\Student.txt'.
Sample content of Student.txt:
'wbrema','Milo','2012-02-15','2012-02-15'

db script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
[PersonID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[HireDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[Enrollment Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PersonID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056929/bulk-load-data-conversion-error-type-mismatch-or-invalid-character-for-the-spec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: add value into you CSV for "PersonID" (or make it autoincrement).

Second: remove quotations from CVS. Your line should be:

```
100,wbrema,Milo,2012-02-15,2012-02-15
```

Now, using statement:

```
BULK
INSERT Person
FROM 'c:\Student.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

... you should be able to import data.

Comment: @Kebab Zahirovic,your solution works although i did  not change the file extention from .txt to csv. How do i read only the PersionID and Last Name only.That will solved the complete challenge i am having.

Comment: ,your solution works although i did not change the file extention from .txt to csv. How do i read only the PersionID and Last Name only.That will solved the complete challenge i am having

Comment: You need to set format file - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178129.aspx. However, you can use following trick  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694394/bulk-insert-into-specific-columns, see solution by @RBarryYoung.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Holding Table  for the raw data along the lines of

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RAW_Person]
(
[PersonID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[HireDate] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Enrollment Date] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

BULK Insert the data into that table

And then perform the text to date conversion as part of the final Insert

```
INSERT INTO 
Person (PersonID, FirstName, LastName, HireDate, [Enrollment Date])
SELECT PersonID, FirstName, LastName, 
CONVERT(date,     [HireDate],        120), 
CONVERT(datetime, [Enrollment Date], 120)
FROM RAW_Person
```

I've used the formatting code 120 (ODBC data format) but you might need some other value look up the CONVERT function in the help files/MSDN for more information

Once you've successfully done that you can get rid of the holding table data

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[RAW_Person]
```

Or if you're never doing this again

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[RAW_Person]
```