# Reading big live appending CSV and update SQL Server C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, csv, bulkinsert

I am trying to read constant appending csv file [may be at frequency if 15-30 seconds]; (starts with 1 row ends till approx. more then 500000 rows, randomly adding number of rows), and insert data into SQL Server, avoiding duplicates, slowness and inflow performance.

I'm using .NET with C# as prime language. Any C# / .NET method that helps BULK INSERT with only specific columns from CSV ?

When I tried the following code, it takes its own time to update records, that compromise the performance and application goes in not responding mode.

```
private void btnPlxl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    string fn;

    fn = this.openFileDialog1.FileName;
    MessageBox.Show("Selected file :" + fn);

    string connectionString;

    SqlConnection conn;
    connectionString = @"Data Source=VKB_LAP_KIRAN\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=ExpoProCli; User ID=sa;Password=Kiran@123";

    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();

    MessageBox.Show("Connection opened");

    //  SELECT* FROM tbl_PS03File
    // BULK INSERT tbl_PS03file from "D:\F_PS03_06760_19102023.CSV" WITH(FORMAT = 'CSV');
    //DATAFILETYPE = 'char'.

    string sqlString = "BULK INSERT tbl_BOFile FROM 'D:\\pl.csv' WITH(FORMAT = 'CSV')";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Bulk Inserted BackOffice File");

    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Connection Closed");
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting?  If you're inserting 500,000 rows into a database, that's going to take a lot of time.

Comment: If you run that same insert in SSMS, how long does it take? How long does it take in your app? If thew two are about the same, why exactly do you think there's a problem?

Comment: It's been said many times in many places: DO NOT perform long-running tasks on the UI thread. Learn how to use asynchronous tasks or multi-threading. You should learn the basic principles involved first, then try to apply them to this specific scenario. If what you try doesn;t work, then you can ask us to help fix it.

Comment: While I agree with @jmcilhinney on it's own that's not the easiest advice for new developers to consume. If _it's been said in many places..._  our role as a community is to provide links to trusted or qualified resources to ensure that the community stays informed and can learn about best practices

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 concepts you have raised here:

- BULK INSERT Specific Rows
- BULK INSERT Specific Columns
- UI Thread Locking (*application goes in not responding mode*)

> The third concept is out of scope and is a well defined topic of its own. The best practices will depend on your runtime:
>
> - WinForms: [How to use a BackgroundWorker?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6481304/1690217)
> - [WinForm Application UI Hangs during Long-Running Operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1216791/1690217)
> - WPF/UWP: [Keep the UI thread responsive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/keep-the-ui-thread-responsive)

To avoid duplicates reading from a live file we need keep a line number reference. If the file write process is streaming characters and not writing appending in whole lines, then we should get the line count first to identify the last line we should attempt to read, otherwise we can append the linenumber by the number of records affected by the command.

> **[BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)**
>
> - [FIRSTROW = first_row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#firstrow--first_row)
>   Specifies the number of the first row to load. The default is the first row in the specified data file. FIRSTROW is 1-based.
> - [LASTROW = last_row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#lastrow--last_row)
>   Specifies the number of the last row to load. The default is 0, which indicates the last row in the specified data file.

A simple implementation that assumes the lines are appended as whole lines would look like this, note that we keep a reference to the `LastRow` outside of the button click method:

- Only use `LASTROW` if you need it, reading the lines in the file can be fast, but usually best to avoid double reading the file if you can, see [What's the fastest way to count the total lines of text file in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19798022/1690217) for pointers.

```
private long LastRow { get;set; } = 1; //Start at line 1, use 2 if you want to skip header rows
...

private void btnPlxl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

    string sqlString = $@"
        BULK INSERT tbl_BOFile 
        FROM 'D:\pl.csv' 
        WITH(FORMAT = 'CSV', FIRSTROW = {LastRow})
    ";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn);
    var rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    LastRow += rows;
    
    MessageBox.Show("Bulk Inserted BackOffice File");
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Connection Closed");
}
```

The specific columns issue should improve the SQL INSERT execution time, but the same number of bytes will need to be read from the file into SQL Server, so depending on how many columns you are excluding and where the time is being lost your results may vary.

This post explores a simple solution for [BULK INSERT into specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19695043/1690217):

> The easiest way is to just create a View that Selects from the target table, listing the columns that you want the data to go to, in the order that they appear in the source file. Then BULK INSERT to your View instead of directly to the Table.

However this relies on the columns in the file that SQL loads matching the target table, which means you still need to manipulate the file, or you bulk insert into a temp or staging table, then project those rows into the *live* table.

An alternative to inserting directly from the live file, while it is being written to (IMO a more robust solution) is to write a function that extracts rows to a temporary file, which you could then also manipulate the columns before handing over to SQL. SQL Server can then have exclusive access to that file, but also the file size would be considerably smaller and consistent. It would serve to reduce contention as reading rows from the file itself should not lock the file for too long and we can handle retries if there are other transient issues with the database execution.

Have a look at this related post about reading from files with shared access: [Read Changes on a text file dynamically c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19229699/1690217)